# Keep VB.NET application running in the background after base form closed

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an application in VB.Net in which a user can schedule emails to be sent in the future. Is there a way to keep my listener thread running in the background after the base form on the application is closed? I would also need to start up the listener when the system boots, but wouldn't want any forms to open at that time.

Example (desired) functionality: I open the application in the morning and schedule three emails, one of which should be sent in three hours, and the other two of which should be sent tomorrow morning. I close the application. In three hours, the first one sends. At the end of the day, I shut down my machine. When I turn it back on tomorrow morning, the other two are sent without me ever opening the application.

I am thinking I need to separate the listener into a service, but want to make sure there isn't an easier way before going down that road.

If I do end up having a separate service and application, can I create an installer that will install both at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the options of your project, [set the “Startup Object” to “Sub Main”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17k74w0c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of of a form name. You might have to disable the setting “Application Framework” first.

Now you have to launch the form manually because it’s no longer done automatically, but on the other hand you can now *control* when to launch it, and your application will exit when it reaches the end of the `Main` method (or when it’s quit explicitly) rather than when the form closes.

Comment: I like this solution; it seems best suited for my specific application, but I am having trouble figuring out how the `Main` method should be written. I am assuming I need to use a loop like `Do While True Loop`. But then how is the form launched when the user wants to enter some data?

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert No loop required. Just launch the form via `Formname.ShowDialog()` – this command will then wait until the form is closed. After that you can perform the waiting until the email should be sent. The easiest way to do *that* is to [put the application’s thread to sleep for a determined amount of time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d.aspx).

Comment: But I don't want the form to launch when the application starts. I want it to start and launch my listener thread, and then allow the user to open/close the form to schedule emails while its running.

Comment: Maybe I need to use the TaskBar method in the answer above?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to keep the program running, you could supply it with the definition for a TaskBar icon, and represent state in your application using the icon's graphic. It would appear over on the right next to the system clock.

Then it's just a matter of reconfiguring your development project so that the application close event is triggered off that icon's menu instead of off the fact that the form is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NotifyIcon control and when the user close the mainform capture the OnClosing Event to Ask the Question if he want to minimize to the tray or exit the application.

Here is the documentation of NotifyIcon control from Microsoft:

[NotifyIcon Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible solution for you here. In the form closing event you can place the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.Visible = False
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This will hide the form and allow it to run in the background until you shutdown the computer. To handle the restart and then send emails I'd suggest adding the emails to be sent to a text file that can be accessed after restart and then adding the program to startup. An even better solution might be to have 2 programs, one that is on startup and is always hidden that checks the text file every 15 minutes (for example) and a second program that is launched when a new email is to be added to the list and it appends the text file with new emails to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry if i am wrong, just proposing a probable solution here)
I think attaching a simple db to hold the email sending schedule information/date-time and loading the application at startup with Notification Icon  (or without Notification Icon but with a shortcut to show user interface/form to feed the emails and schedule information/date-time, if required + BackgroundWorker, if you want the application to go to sleep mode and wake it later to send first scheduled email; after X hours). After sending first email update the db then exit the application. Check the db on startup to send the first email or go to sleep mode if pc boots before sending first email. But, if first email is already sent then send other two scheduled emails (check db date-time). This should do the job...
:)